# Closing questions as not clear without giving feedback

Tags: discussion, reopening

I use the SE platform for some time and I know that in the spirit of this Q&A platform when someone is giving down-votes or close votes he should also provide some feedback to improve the question.

My last question:

[Check all the keys of a keyboard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55198/check-all-the-keys-of-a-keyboard)

was closed for not being clear. But if you look at people that closed it, none,  except for a user whose question I addressed, ever gave feedback.

Comment: I understand your point,  but what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't vote to close this one, but that's mainly because I didn't see it before it was put on hold. However, this sort of thing is pretty common, and I'll explain my usual thought process:

If you're already engaged with one user in comments and I simply *agree* with him, I may feel he has it under control and there's no need to jump in with more comments just asking the same questions. Especially since you went into chat with Doorknob, and were still working things out when it was held (if my view of the timeline is correct), then it was put on hold *while it still had problems*.

I believe this is 100% in keeping with the purpose of putting questions on hold, to "pause" them until they can be answered properly. Jumping in with even more comments (especially if they would just be reiterating the current ones) doesn't seem either appropriate or necessary to me.